# Using ListAdapter with downloaded data in Android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, adapter

I am thinking how to inflate a layout for an Activity, contents of which will be based on downloaded parsed json data.

I thought of using AsyncTask for 1) downloading the data, 2) parsing it and 3) updating UI but the ListAdapter I am using must be on the main thread, so I can't put it in the onPostExecute method of AsyncTask. I am a bit confused as to what approach I should take. Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like in this Example:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Do what ever you want in the *doInBackground(Params... para)*. If you want to update the UI or your ListAdapter. Call *publishProgress(Params pa)* and it will call the *onProgressUpdate(Integer.. progress)*. In this function you could update the UI, update the data or do what you want on the Main Thread.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for thinking about it. I understand this much but what methods would you use in either onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute to update (or even better, inflate for the first time) ListAdapter specifically?

Comment: if you want to update the UI all the time, do it with onprogressupdate. Otherwise if you want to parse the data only one time, then use onepostexecute. Because, when doinbackground finished it calls onpostexecute

Comment: again, I understand this much :) but back to my question, what methods would you call in onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute to achieve what I am intending? thanks